# java: unit test lambda expression inside dispatcher

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, undertow

I have a class:

```
public class RequestHandler implements HttpHandler {
  public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange serverContext) throws Exception {
    serverContext.dispatch(() -> serverContext.getRequestReceiver()
        .receiveFullBytes((httpServerExchange, reqBytes) -> {

          // business logic along with few function call

        }
      )
    );

  }
}
```

I want to write a unit test case to test my business logic. I am not sure how to do it with 2 levels of a lambda expression insider a dispatcher? Can someone please suggest a good way to write test cases?

I know that we can move business logic to new class and can test it (i guess it's better designed) but curious to know what if it's part of some legacy code or something that we can't change, how can we test it?

Comment: IMHO the business logic should be delegated to another class, making it easier to unit-test.

Comment: @Benoit I am thinking about it too. Just curious to know if there is a way to test it without it.

Comment: What is the difference for you, between testing normal buisness logic and one that is wrapped by 2 layers of lambda?

Comment: @second It's more about learning. I can move it to a new class but wondering if it's something in legacy code or in internal library which can't be modified, how should we test it?

Comment: I asked because from a technical standpoint I don't really see a difference between both cases. You just test the buisness logic as usual and if you can't use a real `HttpServerExchange` object you just mock it to pass along the values you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that somewhere in your buisness logic you forward the received message (or whatever you do with it) to somewhere else, you can just test your code as usual.

Note that `HttpServerExchange` is a final class, so you need to use a Mockito version that supports `final` mocking - and you have to enable it, as described [`here`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39).

To get around the lambda expression you need to use [`thenAnswer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-) or [`doAnswer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-) to trigger the invocation of the correct interface method manually.

A simple example could look like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

import io.undertow.io.Receiver;
import io.undertow.io.Receiver.FullBytesCallback;
import io.undertow.server.HttpHandler;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RequestHandlerTest {

    static class BuisnessLogic {
        public void someMethod(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange, byte[] reqBytes) {
        }
    }

    static class RequestHandler implements HttpHandler {

        BuisnessLogic logic;

        public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange serverContext) throws Exception {
            serverContext.dispatch(
                () -> serverContext.getRequestReceiver().receiveFullBytes(
                    (httpServerExchange, reqBytes) -> {
                        logic.someMethod(httpServerExchange, reqBytes);
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    }

    @Mock
    BuisnessLogic logic;

    @InjectMocks
    RequestHandler handler;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        byte[] message = new byte[] {1,2,3};
        HttpServerExchange serverContext = Mockito.mock(HttpServerExchange.class);

        // 1st lambda
        Mockito.when(serverContext.dispatch(Mockito.any(Runnable.class)))
               .thenAnswer((Answer<HttpServerExchange>) invocation -> {

            Runnable runnable = invocation.getArgument(0);
            runnable.run();

            return serverContext;
        });

        // 2nd lambda
        Receiver receiver = Mockito.mock(Receiver.class);
        Mockito.doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {

            FullBytesCallback callback = invocation.getArgument(0);
            callback.handle(serverContext, message);

            return null;

        }).when(receiver).receiveFullBytes(Mockito.any(FullBytesCallback.class));

        Mockito.when(serverContext.getRequestReceiver()).thenReturn(receiver);

        // class under test - method invocation
        handler.handleRequest(serverContext);

        // buisness logic call verification
        ArgumentCaptor<HttpServerExchange> captor1 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpServerExchange.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<byte[]> captor2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(byte[].class);

        Mockito.verify(logic).someMethod(captor1.capture(), captor2.capture());

        Assertions.assertEquals(serverContext, captor1.getValue());
        Assertions.assertEquals(message, captor2.getValue());
    }
}
```

---

As others already mentioned you should only use that approach for legacy code.

A simple refactoring could just push the entire part you need to test into its own method, which - in the example above - would just be the buisness logic itself.

There is no explicit need to test the `undertow` framework yourself.